# How is third-party software (e.g. AnyTrans or iMazing) able to access and modify iPhone/iPad systems without root access?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Software marketed as "iTunes alternatives" such as AnyTrans or iMazing is able to make changes to iOS devices without requiring root access.

They can do things like mirror the device's screen to a PC, manage contacts/apps/files/etc. and they don't require you to install any apps on the device; it's all done via a USB connection.

Programatically-speaking, how is this achieved? I assume it's not via any kind of public API which Apple makes available, so are these programs exploiting loopholes in iOS security or something?

Comment: What does "root" access to do with it?  There are API's for talking to the device.

Comment: I have iMazing and all it does is sync the phone to its own "backup" and then allows you to dig around in that backup for things Apple hides. and like @Mark Wilson said, there are APIs published by Apple that allows you to do that.

Comment: @SteveChambers I, too, have iMazing.  It lets you do a lot more than that.  I do wish Apple hadn't nerfed the iMazing auto-backups.

Comment: @MarcWilson For some reason I assumed root was required to do stuff like screen mirroring. It lets you manage things like contacts and apps in bulk, including re-ordering apps on the device's home screen which is [what I tried to use it for](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/463890/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-to-re-order-or-organise-apps-on-the-ios-home-scree). I found their performance very poor, however, which is why I wondered if they were doing janky stuff instead of using official APIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is achieved through the use of a private protocol that Apple includes with iOS devices. It is not a public API, meaning that its use is not supported by Apple for third party usage, but is created to be used with Apple's own software (such as the iOS integration in Finder, formerly iTunes, Xcode and similar).

Even though the protocol is private, these third parties programs do not need to exploit "loopholes" (security bugs) in iOS in order to make it work. Instead what have been done is that the protocol has been reverse-engineered to re-create the type of documentation that Apple has internally.

This makes it possible for third parties to create software that transmits and receives data over the protocol similar to how Apple's software does it.

There's no "security loophole" in so far that you cannot just plugin any device and extract its data. You must authenticate the pairing of the iOS device and the computer first. This is similar to how you must authenticate when connecting an iOS device to a Mac for the first time, and want to use the Finder integration.

There are considerable drawbacks to using a private protocols. Primarily they are compatibility issues, where the protocol is changed, but third party software developers do not know that it has changed -- and it is the risk of bugs, where third party developers have an incorrect understanding of the protocol that could cause issues in the future.

A very popular reverse-engineering implementation of the client software is `libimobiledevice`:

https://libimobiledevice.org

I would suspect that most, if not all, of these third party softwares are directly using that library or have been heavily inspired by it.

NOTE: I see other answers here mentioning MDM. It is not MDM. The features you speak of are not part of MDM, and the iMazing and AnyTrans software does not use MDM to implement them.

The company behind iMazing also make a different program called "iMazing Configurator", which does use MDM functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a public API to support organisations wanting to manage Apple devices by using a Mobile Device Management (MDM) product. Whilst iMazing is not a full MDM solution, it uses some MDM functionality packaged into a friendly to use product.

iMazing does not document how the product works in detail (it is a commercial product), but do provide their take on [Apple Device Management](https://imazing.com/guides/apple-device-management-glossary). And [here](https://imazing.com/guides/apple-device-management-glossary) too. There are extensive [iMazing Guides](https://imazing.com/guides) - those in the Device Management and Diagnostics sections providing some relevant background.

From Apple's perspective, start with [Apple Platform Deployment](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/deployment/welcome/web) and an [Apple Developer MDM search](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=mdm).

I am not familiar with AnyTrans, but looks like a similar product at a similar price.

Comment: Aha, so they're kind of re-packaging functionality intended for enterprise usage into a consumer app? Is that permitted by Apple? And why doesn't Apple publish these kinds of APIs towards regular developers anyway? Desktop integration with iPhones is years behind what it should be by now. Even free apps like Airdroid - while far from perfect - leave iPhones in the dust for this kind of stuff.

Comment: I suspect (but don't know) that a developer needs a special entitlement to do what iMazing does - not given out freely. Apple has been tightening up (in the name of security) to prevent malware on a Mac being able to do nasties to an iPhone or to read its content. Hence iMazing requires the iPhone password every time it does a backup. I don't think Apple will relax these rules - part of what distinguishes iOS from Android.

Comment: @Clanape The premise here is incorrect - the features you mention are not implemented via MDM. However, the use of MDM is fully permitted by Apple. And Apple does actually publish those APIs towards regular developers. A lot of third party software (commercial and open source) exists that use those APIs.

Comment: @Gilby A special entitlement is not involved here, no.

Comment: @jksoegaard Should I delete my answer as being too superficial and in places incorrect?

Comment: @Gilby I don't want to decide on what other's do with their answer, but your answer does seem to be incorrect in that Apple's MDM APIs do not provide separate APIs for for example mirroring the screen of an iOS device or for copying all the files on the device. But I don't know why you think that iMazing are using MDM with their standard program? (i.e. not iMazing Configurator) Have they stated that anywhere?