# Is there a more efficient way to re-order or organise apps on the iOS home screen other than dragging them around?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

If you have several pages worth of app icons on your iPhone/iPad home screen, dragging them  around one-by-one is a huge pain. It is incredibly inefficient and is one of the things I consider most frustrating about mobile devices in general. Frankly, I can't believe we're in 2023 and problems like this haven't been solved yet.

I tried programs such as AnyTrans and iMazing to do this, but they are incredibly slow and (somehow) end up being just as bad as dragging using the phone.

So is there a better way of re-organising apps like a PC/desktop application which can do this or  even an "export/modify/re-import" type of process which would be faster?

Comment: I didn't find iMazing slow to do it when I messed around just now, but that's just me.  I also think the problem is much overblown.  My phone has looked the same for *years*.  All I ever had to deal with was when the springboard got bigger.  And I never bother with the useless App Library.

Comment: You used to be able to do it in iTunes, yet another useful feature removed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can delete app shortcuts from home screen and access all apps from app library (can access app library on last page by swiping right to left )
2. app library auto sort all apps according to the category. like shopping, social, utilities, Finance and all. also show recently added apps separately.
3. you can enable in setting to add newly downloaded apps in app library and not to home screen to keep your home screen clean

[image: App Library page]

[image: App library setting]